# How to write typescript interface for Window object ethereum that has a request method being called

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, metamask, ethers.js

I am running the following function

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";


async function requestAccount() {
    await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  }
```

The issue I am having is I am using typescript and it complains with the following error

`Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'`

So I was able to fix it with the following

```
declare global {
  interface Window{
    ethereum?:any
  }
}
```

However I don't think this is taking advantage of typescript properly. How would I write it so that the interface value is correct. I assume it should be an object with a method inside, but not sure how to write this in typescript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could tell the compiler to ignore the error if it's not actually something breaking the application, but simply TypeScript yelling at you. You can then run some JavaScript logic to figure out the type, such as `console.log(typeof window.etherum)` or log the entire structure and see what you get. Although sometimes, there are use-cases where you simply have to go with the type definition of `any`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a quite old question but if you or someone else is still looking for an answer, you can use the `ExternalProvider` type of `ethers`.

```js
interface Window {
  ethereum?: import('ethers').providers.ExternalProvider;
}
```

Here is the extracted version of `ExternalProvider` if you're not using ethers

```js
type ExternalProvider = {
  isMetaMask?: boolean;
  isStatus?: boolean;
  host?: string;
  path?: string;
  sendAsync?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }, callback: (error: any, response: any) => void) => void
  send?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }, callback: (error: any, response: any) => void) => void
  request?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }) => Promise<any>
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for: a way to type window.ethereum. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i @metamask/providers
```

Install the above package:

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window{
    ethereum?:MetaMaskInpageProvider
  }
}
```

then

```
const accounts = (await ethereum?.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    })) as string[];
```

Comment: I kind mix the answers, I am using etherjs:
 import { ExternalProvider } from "@ethersproject/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: ExternalProvider;
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the Type Error temporarily by:

- add:
  `declare let window: any` at the top level after your  imports.
  Now your are able to call `window.ethereum` with the warning and Type Error off.

I think this overrides the global window object with a type `any` I'm sure this is not the best way to fix this, sort of a hack but fixes the Type error in the meantime. Let me know if this worked for your case.

Comment: The point is not about bypassing the type error (using `any`), it's about typing `window.ethereum` properly. this does not answer the OP question.